# i want to correct my mysql query

Tags: mysql

i have a table named stops
table am putting here with data

```
CREATE TABLE `stops` (
  `LineID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `StationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DistanceToNext` float DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `stops` (`LineID`, `StationID`, `Rank`, `DistanceToNext`) VALUES
('1', 132, 1, 1.469),
('1', 90, 2, 1.114),
('1', 213, 3, 1.462),
('1', 145, 4, 1.084),
('1', 239, 5, 0.875),
('1', 8, 6, 0.727),
('1', 50, 7, 0.588),
('1', 112, 8, 0.922),
('1', 99, 9, 0.663),
('1', 47, 10, 1.048),
('1', 66, 11, 0.802),
('1', 296, 12, 0.639),
('1', 193, 13, 0.631),
('1', 151, 14, 0.716),
('1', 57, 15, 0.524),
('1', 119, 16, 1.034),
('1', 276, 17, 0.982),
('1', 18, 18, 1.055),
('1', 109, 19, 1.369),
('1', 253, 20, 1.097),
('1', 182, 21, 1.449),
('1', 234, 22, 1.094),
('1', 273, 23, 1.18),
('1', 21, 24, 1.146),
('1', 54, 25, 0),
('10', 35, 1, 1.192),
('10', 34, 2, 2.297),
('10', 218, 3, 0.519),
('10', 174, 4, 0.406),
('10', 173, 5, 0.418),
('10', 48, 6, 0.379),
('10', 88, 7, 0.501),
('10', 176, 8, 0.578),
('10', 125, 9, 0.876),
('10', 51, 10, 0.959),
('10', 13, 11, 0.414),
('10', 135, 12, 1.13),
('10', 281, 13, 0.99),
('10', 84, 14, 0.624),
('10', 297, 15, 0.509),
('10', 283, 16, 1.075),
('10', 152, 17, 0.356),
('10', 187, 18, 0.753),
('10', 63, 19, 0.386),
('10', 171, 20, 0.512),
('10', 44, 21, 0.363),
('10', 128, 22, 1.112),
('10', 107, 23, 0),
('11', 57, 1, 0.524),
('11', 119, 2, 0.561),
('11', 247, 3, 0.538),
('11', 9, 4, 0.847),
('11', 252, 5, 0.88),
('11', 114, 6, 0.669),
('11', 20, 7, 0.922),
('11', 243, 8, 0.499),
('11', 126, 9, 0.51),
('11', 206, 10, 0.591),
('11', 290, 11, 0.887),
('11', 231, 12, 1.137),
('11', 158, 13, 0),
('12', 225, 1, 0.872),
('12', 170, 2, 1.155),
('12', 168, 3, 0.622),
('12', 127, 4, 0.688),
('12', 134, 5, 0.593),
('12', 1, 6, 0.246),
('12', 204, 7, 0.443),
('12', 269, 8, 0.23),
('12', 184, 9, 0.6),
('12', 294, 10, 0.771),
('12', 272, 11, 0.623),
('12', 153, 12, 0.478),
('12', 66, 13, 0.658),
('12', 11, 14, 0.346),
('12', 286, 15, 0.447),
('12', 261, 16, 0.507),
('12', 283, 17, 0.428),
('12', 251, 18, 0.359),
('12', 185, 19, 0.722),
('12', 180, 20, 0.598),
('12', 95, 21, 0.57),
('12', 196, 22, 0.531),
('12', 306, 23, 0.82),
('12', 299, 24, 0.51),
('12', 67, 25, 1.135),
('12', 233, 26, 1.127),
('12', 69, 27, 0.699),
('12', 159, 28, 0),
('13', 10, 1, 0.828),
('13', 142, 2, 1.255),
('13', 103, 3, 1.831),
('13', 154, 4, 1.376),
('13', 223, 5, 0.828),
('13', 38, 6, 7.735),
('13', 266, 7, 1.054),
('13', 17, 8, 0.806),
('13', 265, 9, 1.943),
('13', 45, 10, 1.298),
('13', 157, 11, 0.722),
('13', 111, 12, 1.027),
('13', 230, 13, 0.561),
('13', 116, 14, 0.579),
('13', 133, 15, 0.442),
('13', 205, 16, 0.459),
('13', 147, 17, 0.444),
('13', 272, 18, 1.239),
('13', 177, 19, 0.713),
('13', 47, 20, 0.638),
('13', 121, 21, 0.481),
('13', 298, 22, 0.65),
('13', 268, 23, 0.639),
('13', 84, 24, 0.778),
('13', 180, 25, 0.506),
('13', 104, 26, 0.754),
('13', 200, 27, 0.46),
('13', 209, 28, 1.071),
('13', 232, 29, 1.054),
('13', 164, 30, 0.94),
('13', 165, 31, 0.676),
('13', 58, 32, 0),
('2', 217, 1, 0.983),
('2', 301, 2, 1.28),
('2', 50, 3, 0.478),
('2', 292, 4, 0.633),
('2', 71, 5, 0.616),
('2', 178, 6, 0.703),
('2', 305, 7, 0.656),
('2', 258, 8, 0.713),
('2', 205, 9, 0.485),
('2', 26, 10, 0.675),
('2', 204, 11, 0.71),
('2', 7, 12, 0.643),
('2', 16, 13, 0.975),
('2', 130, 14, 0.955),
('2', 287, 15, 0.401),
('2', 124, 16, 0.511),
('2', 64, 17, 0.989),
('2', 20, 18, 0.482),
('2', 72, 19, 0.516),
('2', 172, 20, 0.524),
('2', 199, 21, 0.557),
('2', 201, 22, 0.669),
('2', 3, 23, 0.666),
('2', 14, 24, 0.362),
('2', 182, 25, 0),
('3', 212, 1, 0.749),
('3', 5, 2, 0.508),
('3', 149, 3, 0.628),
('3', 220, 4, 0.542),
('3', 198, 5, 0.797),
('3', 308, 6, 0.573),
('3', 166, 7, 0.65),
('3', 305, 8, 0.879),
('3', 92, 9, 0.511),
('3', 272, 10, 0.358),
('3', 117, 11, 0.47),
('3', 189, 12, 0.462),
('3', 246, 13, 0.614),
('3', 36, 14, 0.618),
('3', 282, 15, 0.615),
('3', 250, 16, 0.496),
('3', 9, 17, 0.536),
('3', 291, 18, 0.313),
('3', 252, 19, 1.378),
('3', 194, 20, 0.488),
('3', 262, 21, 0.755),
('3', 199, 22, 1.329),
('3', 106, 23, 1.062),
('3', 219, 24, 0.862),
('3', 105, 25, 0),
('3Bis', 106, 1, 0.52),
('3Bis', 197, 2, 0.545),
('3Bis', 267, 3, 0.594),
('3Bis', 231, 4, 0),
('4', 224, 1, 0.391),
('4', 285, 2, 0.517),
('4', 168, 3, 0.411),
('4', 56, 4, 0.395),
('4', 16, 5, 0.685),
('4', 110, 6, 0.562),
('4', 108, 7, 0.472),
('4', 53, 8, 0.406),
('4', 288, 9, 0.394),
('4', 250, 10, 0.488),
('4', 91, 11, 0.347),
('4', 144, 12, 0.433),
('4', 57, 13, 0.382),
('4', 62, 14, 0.414),
('4', 275, 15, 0.558),
('4', 187, 16, 0.559),
('4', 270, 17, 0.445),
('4', 280, 18, 0.642),
('4', 278, 19, 0.619),
('4', 180, 20, 0.717),
('4', 300, 21, 0.381),
('4', 249, 22, 0.614),
('4', 81, 23, 0.373),
('4', 181, 24, 0.441),
('4', 2, 25, 0.679),
('4', 238, 26, 0),
('5', 27, 1, 3.051),
('5', 28, 2, 1.303),
('5', 89, 3, 1.139),
('5', 118, 4, 1.346),
('5', 228, 5, 0.623),
('5', 192, 6, 0.747),
('5', 138, 7, 1.078),
('5', 124, 8, 0.401),
('5', 287, 9, 1.459),
('5', 110, 10, 0.562),
('5', 108, 11, 0.636),
('5', 122, 12, 0.521),
('5', 252, 13, 0.647),
('5', 186, 14, 0.554),
('5', 254, 15, 0.503),
('5', 37, 16, 0.453),
('5', 18, 17, 0.818),
('5', 245, 18, 0.425),
('5', 107, 19, 0.513),
('5', 274, 20, 0.551),
('5', 43, 21, 0.556),
('5', 207, 22, 0),
('6', 50, 1, 0.474),
('6', 129, 2, 0.537),
('6', 29, 3, 0.592),
('6', 295, 4, 0.607),
('6', 195, 5, 0.49),
('6', 25, 6, 0.592),
('6', 83, 7, 0.604),
('6', 135, 8, 0.469),
('6', 42, 9, 0.967),
('6', 284, 10, 0.367),
('6', 196, 11, 1.11),
('6', 180, 12, 0.495),
('6', 87, 13, 0.514),
('6', 249, 14, 0.614),
('6', 81, 15, 0.483),
('6', 271, 16, 0.884),
('6', 113, 17, 0.642),
('6', 70, 18, 0.727),
('6', 207, 19, 0.718),
('6', 183, 20, 0.6),
('6', 61, 21, 0.808),
('6', 244, 22, 0.727),
('6', 22, 23, 1.055),
('6', 82, 24, 0.768),
('6', 80, 25, 0.659),
('6', 19, 26, 0.374),
('6', 202, 27, 0.693),
('6', 182, 28, 0),
('7', 131, 1, 0.982),
('7', 98, 2, 1.812),
('7', 12, 3, 0.962),
('7', 226, 4, 0.494),
('7', 68, 5, 0.782),
('7', 77, 6, 0.384),
('7', 256, 7, 0.926),
('7', 287, 8, 0.402),
('7', 148, 9, 0.471),
('7', 55, 10, 0.548),
('7', 108, 11, 0.935),
('7', 211, 12, 0.757),
('7', 41, 13, 0.367),
('7', 141, 14, 0.736),
('7', 59, 15, 0.308),
('7', 189, 16, 0.466),
('7', 242, 17, 0.514),
('7', 193, 18, 0.842),
('7', 216, 19, 0.575),
('7', 57, 20, 1.287),
('7', 215, 21, 0.552),
('7', 289, 22, 0.985),
('7', 128, 23, 0.405),
('7', 208, 24, 0.307),
('7', 46, 25, 0.437),
('7', 143, 26, 0.735),
('7', 207, 27, 0.57),
('7', 293, 28, 0.444),
('7', 161, 29, 1.412),
('7', 140, 30, 0.737),
('7', 302, 31, 1.018),
('7', 304, 32, 1),
('7', 303, 33, 3.635),
('7', 235, 34, 0.517),
('7', 222, 35, 0.543),
('7', 236, 36, 1.102),
('7', 203, 37, 0.881),
('7', 160, 38, 0),
('7bis', 148, 1, 0.546),
('7bis', 124, 2, 0.47),
('7bis', 30, 3, 0.854),
('7bis', 39, 4, 0.863),
('7bis', 32, 5, 0.533),
('7bis', 79, 6, 0.584),
('7bis', 206, 7, 0.713),
('7bis', 240, 8, 0),
('8', 15, 1, 0.464),
('8', 150, 2, 0.721),
('8', 33, 3, 0.522),
('8', 96, 4, 0.253),
('8', 65, 5, 0.703),
('8', 135, 6, 1.033),
('8', 85, 7, 0.552),
('8', 137, 8, 0.713),
('8', 121, 9, 1.113),
('8', 66, 10, 0.478),
('8', 153, 11, 0.742),
('8', 189, 12, 0.823),
('8', 255, 13, 0.462),
('8', 115, 14, 0.617),
('8', 31, 15, 0.621),
('8', 288, 16, 1.081),
('8', 252, 17, 0.558),
('8', 97, 18, 0.233),
('8', 279, 19, 0.425),
('8', 60, 20, 0.543),
('8', 18, 21, 0.774),
('8', 139, 22, 0.932),
('8', 94, 23, 0.391),
('8', 253, 24, 0.527),
('8', 179, 25, 0.864),
('8', 80, 26, 0.845),
('8', 175, 27, 0.367),
('8', 237, 28, 0.773),
('8', 221, 29, 1.094),
('8', 146, 30, 0.938),
('8', 49, 31, 1.014),
('8', 86, 32, 1.81),
('8', 163, 33, 1.199),
('8', 162, 34, 0.869),
('8', 74, 35, 0.833),
('8', 76, 36, 1.368),
('8', 75, 37, 0),
('9', 214, 1, 0.912),
('9', 24, 2, 0.699),
('9', 169, 3, 1.482),
('9', 229, 4, 0.601),
('9', 93, 5, 0.374),
('9', 174, 6, 0.406),
('9', 173, 7, 0.65),
('9', 123, 8, 0.41),
('9', 248, 9, 0.54),
('9', 136, 10, 0.788),
('9', 259, 11, 1.052),
('9', 295, 12, 0.772),
('9', 120, 13, 0.788),
('9', 4, 14, 0.975),
('9', 99, 15, 0.361),
('9', 277, 16, 0.622),
('9', 177, 17, 0.592),
('9', 264, 18, 0.91),
('9', 117, 19, 0.557),
('9', 59, 20, 0.629),
('9', 255, 21, 0.462),
('9', 115, 22, 0.617),
('9', 31, 23, 0.621),
('9', 288, 24, 1.081),
('9', 252, 25, 0.647),
('9', 186, 26, 0.706),
('9', 263, 27, 0.743),
('9', 307, 28, 0.691),
('9', 52, 29, 0.52),
('9', 260, 30, 0.856),
('9', 182, 31, 0.675),
('9', 40, 32, 0.588),
('9', 167, 33, 0.476),
('9', 227, 34, 1.478),
('9', 257, 35, 1.419),
('9', 78, 36, 0.79),
('9', 155, 37, 0);
```

this table have a relation table subwayline,but i dont know for this query that table needed or not,am adding that table too here

```
CREATE TABLE `subwaylines` (
  `LineID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Start1` time NOT NULL,
  `Start2` time NOT NULL,
  `EndW1` time NOT NULL,
  `EndW2` time NOT NULL,
  `EndWE1` time NOT NULL,
  `EndWE2` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `subwaylines` (`LineID`, `Start1`, `Start2`, `EndW1`, `EndW2`, `EndWE1`, `EndWE2`) VALUES
('1', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:40:00', '00:40:00', '01:40:00', '01:40:00'),
('10', '05:30:00', '05:35:00', '00:21:00', '00:47:00', '01:21:00', '01:47:00'),
('11', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:56:00', '00:59:00', '01:56:00', '01:59:00'),
('12', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:39:00', '00:38:00', '01:39:00', '01:38:00'),
('13', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:37:00', '00:37:00', '01:37:00', '01:37:00'),
('14', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '01:00:00', '01:01:00', '02:00:00', '02:01:00'),
('2', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:40:00', '00:42:00', '01:40:00', '01:42:00'),
('3', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:45:00', '00:44:00', '01:45:00', '01:44:00'),
('3bis', '05:32:00', '05:27:00', '01:11:00', '01:04:00', '02:11:00', '02:04:00'),
('4', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:47:00', '00:47:00', '01:47:00', '01:47:00'),
('5', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:41:00', '00:42:00', '01:41:00', '01:42:00'),
('6', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:42:00', '00:41:00', '01:41:00', '01:41:00'),
('7', '05:29:00', '05:28:00', '00:27:00', '00:20:00', '01:27:00', '01:20:00'),
('7BIS', '05:44:00', '05:31:00', '01:07:00', '00:54:00', '02:07:00', '01:54:00'),
('8', '05:30:00', '05:30:00', '00:24:00', '00:24:00', '01:24:00', '01:24:00'),
('9', '05:30:00', '05:24:00', '00:26:00', '00:26:00', '01:26:00', '01:26:00');
```

Calculate the average distance between two stops for each line .

i have done a query .but am not sure its correct.
please help me

```
  SELECT AVG(pd.pcount)
     FROM(SELECT LineID,SUM(DistanceToNext) as pcount
     FROM stops
     GROUP BY StationID HAVING COUNT(StationID)=2) as pd
```

Comment: You want the average distance between consecutive stops?

Comment: Please go read [ask], particularly regarding what a proper question title should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the average distance between two stops for each line, I think a simple aggregation query should work:

```
SELECT
    LineID, AVG(DistanceToNext) AS avg_distance
FROM stops
GROUP BY
    LineID;
```

The second subway table appears to be a timetable of some sort, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with distances.

Comment: @susana My first query was not what you want.  Reload the page.

Comment: query seems right but dont have to take all stops,need avarage distance between two stops for each line id, i think this query will take average of all stops for line id

Comment: So are you saying if a line has 10 stops, then you want to examine 10*10 = 100 distances?  I don't understand what you want here.

Comment: If the distance in the table represents all the adjacent distances which you want to average, then my query should work for you.  Keep in mind, I _don't_ take the average over the entire table, just over the stops for each separate line.

Comment: how we take avaerage distance of two stops of a lineid?

Comment: @susana Please tell us what you are trying to calculate here.  Regarding what you just asked, what does this even mean?

Comment: Calculate the average distance between two stops for each line

Comment: two stops means we have to take distance between two stops for each line no? in this query all stops for a line will take no? thats my doubt

Comment: @susana If I understand your table correctly, those distances _already_ represent the distances between each pair of adjacent stops.  So all you need to do is average that column, for each line.  Does this seem reasonable to you?